# UnoCSS arbitrary breakpoints

Tags: tailwind-css, unocss

How can I use arbitrary breakpoints in UnoCSS?

I'm trying the regular tailwind class (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#using-custom-breakpoints):

```
min-[780px]:flex-row
```

But it's not applying. I'm using UnoCSS Wind preset about which there's some info here: https://unocss.dev/presets/wind

Comment: 1- In your `unocss.config.js` or where you configure UnoCSS, define your breakpoints 2- Use the Breakpoint in Your Class `<div class="md:flex-row ...">`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically asking about arbitrary breakpoints, not how to define breakpoints in the theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom rules in UnoCSS for arbitrary breakpoints involves using dynamic rules with regular expressions

```js
// uno.config.js or unocss.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'unocss'

export default defineConfig({
  rules: [
    // rule for arbitrary breakpoints...
    [/^min-w-(\d+)px:(.*)$/, ([, minWidth, className]) => {
      return {
        [`@media (min-width: ${minWidth}px)`]: {
          [`.${className}`]: { /* your CSS here . like..>*/ display: 'flex },
        },
      }
    }],
  ],
})
```

Custom Breakpoints in HTML

```html
<div class="min-[780px]:flex-row ...">
  <!-- flex row on screens wider than 780px... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I see that with this solution you don't have the flexibility that arbitrary breakpoints in vanilla trailwind have, for example you would have to define display: flex inside your rules, but with vanila tailwind you could just use an arbitrary breakpoint with any class you like, inline, and not pre-configured. Is it not possible in UnoCSS? Thanks

Comment: Indeed, the flexibility offered by Tailwind CSS for using arbitrary breakpoints with any class is not directly available in UnoCSS in the same manner. UnoCSS is highly customizable, but achieving the same level of inline, arbitrary breakpoint functionality as in Tailwind would require more complex custom configurations

Comment: Fair enough thank you very much